# How to give format (`miliseconds` in this case) to specific columns in several objects (but not all) from a list in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a device that records several data per second for several days. When I download the data I get several files, since all the information can't be stored in one file.

In this regard, I have a list `list` where I've merged as different objects the different files created by the device. My problem is that the first column for some of the objects (`obj4`) is considered as `seconds` instead of `miliseconds`. Here I show a reproducible example:

```
obj1<- data.frame(V1=c(0.344,0.567,0.734,0.954),
                  V2=c(-123,-101,-90,-68),
                  V3=c(23,48,79,103),
                  V4=c(-98,-45,-109,-87))

obj2<- data.frame(V1=c(1008,1325,1758,1985),
                  V2=c(-123,-101,-90,-68),
                  V3=c(23,48,79,103),
                  V4=c(-98,-45,-109,-87))

obj3<- data.frame(V1=c(2.058,2.245,2.487,2.653),
                  V2=c(-123,-101,-90,-68),
                  V3=c(23,48,79,103),
                  V4=c(-98,-45,-109,-87))

obj4<- data.frame(V1=c(2789,2856,2983,3089),
                  V2=c(-123,-101,-90,-68),
                  V3=c(23,48,79,103),
                  V4=c(-98,-45,-109,-87))

df1<- list(obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4)
df1

[[1]]
   V1   V2  V3   V4
1 0.344 -123  23  -98
2 0.567 -101  48  -45
3 0.734  -90  79 -109
4 0.954  -68 103  -87

[[2]]
    V1   V2  V3   V4
1 1008 -123  23  -98
2 1325 -101  48  -45
3 1758  -90  79 -109
4 1985  -68 103  -87

[[3]]
    V1   V2  V3   V4
1 2.058 -123  23  -98
2 2.245 -101  48  -45
3 2.487  -90  79 -109
4 2.653  -68 103  -87

[[4]]
    V1   V2  V3   V4
1 2789 -123  23  -98
2 2856 -101  48  -45
3 2983  -90  79 -109
4 3089  -68 103  -87
```

I need to format the first column `V1` of the objects `obj2` and `obj4` to have them also in the same format than the rest of the objects. Here is what I would expect:

```
df1

[[1]]
   V1   V2  V3   V4
1 0.344 -123  23  -98
2 0.567 -101  48  -45
3 0.734  -90  79 -109
4 0.954  -68 103  -87

[[2]]
    V1   V2  V3   V4
1 1.008 -123  23  -98
2 1.325 -101  48  -45
3 1.758  -90  79 -109
4 1.985  -68 103  -87

[[3]]
    V1   V2  V3   V4
1 2.058 -123  23  -98
2 2.245 -101  48  -45
3 2.487  -90  79 -109
4 2.653  -68 103  -87

[[4]]
    V1   V2  V3   V4
1 2.789 -123  23  -98
2 2.856 -101  48  -45
3 2.983  -90  79 -109
4 3.089  -68 103  -87
```

Does anyone know how to deal with it?

Comment: Now is correct!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subset first column of last element in the list and divide by 1000.

```
df1[[4]][1] <- df1[[4]][1]/1000


df1
#[[1]]
#     V1   V2  V3   V4
#1 0.344 -123  23  -98
#2 0.567 -101  48  -45
#3 0.734  -90  79 -109
#4 0.954  -68 103  -87

#[[2]]
#     V1   V2  V3   V4
#1 1.008 -123  23  -98
#2 1.325 -101  48  -45
#3 1.758  -90  79 -109
#4 1.985  -68 103  -87

#[[3]]
#     V1   V2  V3   V4
#1 2.058 -123  23  -98
#2 2.245 -101  48  -45
#3 2.487  -90  79 -109
#4 2.653  -68 103  -87

#[[4]]
#     V1   V2  V3   V4
#1 2.789 -123  23  -98
#2 2.856 -101  48  -45
#3 2.983  -90  79 -109
#4 3.089  -68 103  -87
```

If the length of `df1` is not known beforehand, we can do

```
df1[[length(df1)]][1] <- df1[[length(df1)]][1]/1000
```